# translateX and overflow hidden doesn't work as expected

Tags: css

This is my WordPress Starter Theme: http://starter.devurl.net/

Relevant HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <ul class="skiplinks">...</ul>
        <div id="site-wrap">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#site-wrap {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-250px);
}
```

**Viewing the website in mobile (in Chrome's Devtools).**

body has `overflow-x: hidden;`
div#site-wrap has `transform: translateX(-250px);`

As far as I grasp the idea, #site-wrap suppose to move to the left and leave a blank space at the right, without any horizontal scroll to the sides.

Notice the website direction is **RTL**, but it's not supposed be a problem, and I'd like to keep it that way without using ltr anywhere in the document.

Thank you!

Comment: I agree, I can't seem to recreate the same situation in jsfiddle. Sorry about that...

Comment: So, after doing some diagnosis and troubleshooting, I *believe* the solution is to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `html` selector: `html { overflow-x: hidden;}`.  Can you try that and see if it fixes the issue for you?

Comment: YES! I still don't understand why it acts like that though... the <body> has overflow-x hidden already, why should the html get one also?

Comment: Things are odd on mobile.  I'm going to turn it into an answer, I hope you appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience with mobile, due to the way they render various things, you sometimes need to address the `html` element as well to ensure things work properly.

This is what it looks like (before fix) on a Samsung Galaxy (I've added borders to elements to illustrate what's happening):

Black: html element
Green: Body element
Red: site-wrap element
Blue: skiplinks element

[image: Diagnosis on BrowserStack]
Notice that the `body` and `html` are actually only the right 250px.

By adding this:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

the problem seems to be resolved:

[image: With HTML overflow-x hidden]

I'm sure someone smarter than I am will be able to explain why!